# How to test the values of two different cells in excel?

Tags: excel

How can I test to make sure that the values between two cells are both non-zero?

This may be an exercise of my rustiness in certain areas of math but I have two columns of values in an excel spreadsheet. In a third column to the right, I'm taking 80% of one and 20% of another and getting the sum. However, this is throwing off the calculation I'm trying to do often because the value in several cells is zero in one but not the other. How can I only apply the 80% or 20% when both values are not zero?

Comment: Using what? C# Excel Interop, or...? If so, you could retrieve the values from both cells and compare them.

Comment: It says in the question that it is excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your columns are A and B, the following will work in column C:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>0,B1<>0),(0.8*A1)+(0.2*B1),"A value equals zero")
```

In plain language:

If A and B are both not equal to zero, apply the calculation.

Else, warn the user that a value in column A or B equals zero.

**Edit:**

In response to the comment:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>0,B1<>0),(0.8*A1)+(0.2*B1),SUM(A1:B1))
```

In plain language:

If A and B are both not equal to zero, apply the calculation.

Else, sum the two values.  The sum is equal to the non-zero value in column A or B.

Comment: Is there a way to return the value of the non-zero cell? Instead of the "A value equals zero" string?

Comment: Yes.  Is it possible that both values equal zero?  That would change how the logic is implemented.

Comment: Yes, there are a few cases like that. How much would it mess up the logic? Because to answer my own comment, I was thinking I could just replace the string with a sum of the two cells.

Comment: @David Yes, the sum of the two values will return the non-zero value.  I updated my answer.